# "Axis" names for dimnames of multidimensional array in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

How do you label dimensions in an R array? **(note: I don't mean "how do you label each point on the axis within each dimension!)**. For example, suppose I create the following matrix:

```
foo <- array(NA, dim = c(2, 2, 2), dimnames = list(c(1, 2), c(3, 4), c(5, 6)))
```

I would like the first dimension to be labelled "foo," the second dimension to be labelled "bar," and the third dimension to be labelled "baz" so that the user of `foo` can immediately see what each dimension represents.

A workaround I am aware of is to return data as a dataframe, using column names to label the various dimensions. For various reasons though, I would prefer to keep the data as denormalized (is that the right direction?) as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
dims = dim(foo)
dim_names = c("foo", "bar", "baz")

dimnames(foo) = 
  lapply(seq_along(dims), 
         function(ii)
           paste0(dim_names[ii], seq(to = cumsum(dims)[ii], 
                                     length.out = dims[ii])))

foo
# , , baz5
#
#      bar3 bar4
# foo1   NA   NA
# foo2   NA   NA
# 
# , , baz6
#
#      bar3 bar4
# foo1   NA   NA
# foo2   NA   NA
```